# How to write Mule muleEventContext.getMessage().getPayloadAsString() in MEL in mule-config

Tags: mule

I've a soap service flow which gets inbound request through `<cxf:proxy-service>`. I have a java component right after it to get payload as String.

Here is my flow:

```
<flow name="soapService">
    <http:inbound-endpoint address="${service.address}" exchange-pattern="request-response">
        <cxf:proxy-service wsdlLocation="classpath:service.wsdl" namespace="http://pennmutual.com/services/mvi" service="MVIService" enableMuleSoapHeaders="false"/>                
    </http:inbound-endpoint>        
    <component class="test.GetPayload" />
  .
  .
  .
 </flow>
```

And here is my GetPayload class:

```
public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {
    String requestXml = null;
    try {

        requestXml = eventContext.getMessage().getPayloadAsString();
        logger.debug("Request XML " + requestXml);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return requestXml;
}
```

I need a way to get rid of GetPayload class and do same thing in my `mule-config`. I tried 
`<object-to-string-transformer/>`

and
`<set-payload value="#[message.payloadAsString]"/>`

but `message.payloadAsString` throws exception. I don't understand why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use: `#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]`

From: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/MEL+Cheat+Sheet#MELCheatSheet-PayloadandAttachments

Comment: Thanks for your response. But there is no such method as `getPayloadAs()` in `MuleMessage` class while there is a method as `getPayloadAsString()`

Comment: MEL wraps the `MuleMessage` with a http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/3.4.0/apidocs/index.html?org/mule/el/context/MessageContext.html and binds it as the `message` variable.

Comment: so, message is really the muleContext? Thank you!

Comment: No it is not. In my comment, I have not linked `MuleContext` but `MessageContext`.

Comment: Sorry mistyped, meant MessageContext only